# Powershell Script to clean up file names

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

I have a script that I use to clean up file names to match my preferred style/format. It works as is, but its kinda ugly and does a loop for each change. Ideally it would process all the changes for each file name at once and then proceed to the next, rather then grabbing the gci every time.

Any suggestions on making this a bit more elegant/streamlined? Thanks!

```
#need this for camel casing later
$Culture = Get-Culture
#Remove Other Tags
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('(retail)','') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('(epub)','') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('(mobi)','') }
#Pad Dashes
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('-',' - ') }
#Replace Underscores with Spaces
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('_',' ') }
#Replace dots with space except for in the extension
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '\.',' ') + $_.Extension }
#Rename to Camel Casecd 
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$Culture.textinfo.totitlecase($_.FullName)}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace(' .','.') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.Epub','.epub') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.Pdf','.pdf') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.Mp3','.mp3') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('For','for') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('And','and') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('In','in') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('On','on') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('Of','of') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('From','from') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('To','to') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace(' A ',' a ') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace(' i',' I') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('epubo O','epub') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('Html','HTML') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('Css','CSS') }
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('Css','CSS') }
#Remove Double Spaces 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('  ',' ') }
```

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that you query the same list of files 25 times. I'd recommend to query them once, make all changes to their names and rename them then ... only once.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is probably not complete but it might be an inspiration for further improvements  ;-)

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    $NewBaseName = $_.BaseName -replace '\(epub\)' -replace '\(mobi\)' -replace '\(retail\)'
    $NewBaseName = $NewBaseName -replace '-', ' - ' -replace '_', ' ' -replace '\.', ' ' -replace '\s+', ' '
    $NewBaseName = $NewBaseName.toLower() -replace 'epubo O', 'epub' -creplace 'html', 'HTML' -creplace 'css', 'CSS'
    $NewExtension = $_.Extension.toLower()
    $NewName = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory -ChildPath ($NewBaseName + $NewExtension)
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName
}
```

This way you traverse the directories only once. That should at least be faster than your approach.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking, however, this code does not work recursively for directories.  

It works good for a single subfolder.  I think I will be able to fix it but if you have nested folders the Join-Path part doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*doesn't work correctly*"?

Comment: It mangles the path and errors out.  I haven't had a chance to dig in but I think when it's a folder you would not want to use the path.child.  But this basically got me 90% where I need be.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah ... I see ... but there's simple solution ... simply add `-Directory` to the `Get-ChildItem` command ... I updated my suggestion. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal if you think it is elegant :

```
$hash = @{'(retail)' = ''; '(epub)' = ''; '(mobi)' = ''; 'And' = 'and' } #To be completed
    
$Culture = Get-Culture
$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $name = $item.Name
    foreach ($h in $hash.Keys) {
        $name = $name.Replace($h, $hash.$h)
    } 
    Rename-Item -Path $item.FullName -NewName $name
}
```